# How do I split this huge image 15104 * 11264

Tags: image, split, tiling

Paint.net dies opening this image, and MS paint as well.I don't know how to open this file for editing.Actually, I set out to break this image (its a map of my area) and load it to my phone (moto rokr e6),which does not have a GPS at the moment.

TileMage is giving up the splitting as well, throwing out of memory exception !.

I know photoshop could do it, but I don't have the licence for it. Any freeware application to do this.

Can GIMP do it ?

Please advise.
Thanks,

Comment: I was about to shout GIMP.. I don't know, but it's free to try I guess :-P Interesting question +1

Comment: how large (Mb) is the file and what dpi? I can only say to try Gimp...keep us posted...

Comment: Paint.net crashes for a reason explained here : http://paintdotnet.forumer.com/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=20503

File size is : 45.7 MB , bit depth : 24

Comment: Doesn't this kind of stuff belong on superuser.com if you aren't asking about how to handle this in code (and not just looking for an app that was well written)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) should be able to handle an image this large. [`convert`](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/convert.php) is what you'd use. Just don't expect it to happen particularly quickly.

Comment: I recommend too. `convert -resize 15104x11264 someimage.png hugeimage.png` took about 1 GB of memory and about 1 minute (including swapping :)).

Comment: Sorry,the does the command "convert" split ? .Let me rake their doc. Thanks

Comment: works like a charm ! - Let me see how it looks on the phone . Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use imagemagick's stream command instead of convert. It uses only little RAM no matter how large the image is: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8756798/1034454